# Multiple IF statements showing image when input are completed

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I cant seem to get multiple IF statements to work on my script. I want an image to appear when three input fields have text in, and not when only one or two have text in. Any help would be much appreciated.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="email-case-study-checker.php" onsubmit="return submitToHighslide(this)">

       Full Name  <span class="required">*</span><br />
        <input name="your_name" type="text" id="name" title="Enter your full name" size="36" maxlength="50"><br /><br />

        Company  <span class="required">*</span><br />
        <input name="your_company" type="text" id="company" title="Enter your company name" size="36" maxlength="50"><br /><br />

        Email Address  <span class="required">*</span><br />
        <input name="your_email" type="text" id="email" title="Enter your email address" size="36" maxlength="50"><br /><br />

 <div id="hiddenpdf"> <a href="pdfs/Southend-On-Sea-Council-Case-Study.pdf"> Right click and save link as to download pdf</a></div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
function hiddenpdf() 
{
    if(document.getElementById('name').value == "") {
    if(document.getElementById('company').value == "") {
    if(document.getElementById('email').value == "");}

    {
            document.getElementById('hiddenpdf').style.display = 'none';

    }
    }
    else 
    {
    document.getElementById('hiddenpdf').style.display = 'block';   
    }

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (document.getElementById('name').value != "" && document.getElementById('company').value != "" && document.getElementById('email').value != ""){
   document.getElementById('hiddenpdf').style.display = 'block'; 
}else{
    document.getElementById('hiddenpdf').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Hope this helps.

You have a syntax error in your code. Above solution checks with "and" logic and will only execute 'block' statement if all three conditions are met otherwise it will move over to else statement.

Comment: Thanks Asif, much appreciated. Sorry for the error in the code, I should of checked it properly before rushing to post the question.